Quasi-random number sequence that is unbiased on the unit interval
I am trying to use the Halton sequence for a quasi-Monte Carlo method in two dimensions. However, a problem I am running into is that the mean of the sequence is always less than one-half (except for select sequence lengths), making it biased.
As best as I can tell, the mean of the Halton sequence will only be exactly .5 if $n = b^i - 1$, where $n$ is the number of sample points, $b$ is the base, and $i$ is some nonnegative integer. At all other $n$, the mean of the sequence is less than .5.
I would like to "adjust" this sequence such that the average is .5 for arbitrary $n$.
My idea is to first generate a longer Halton sequence, of length $b^{\lceil\log_b n\rceil} - 1$, and then keep the first $b^{\lfloor\log_b n\rfloor} - 1$ values. The mean of each of these sequences will be .5. Then, of the remaining values, choose $n - \left(b^{\lfloor\log_b n\rfloor} - 1\right)$ of them such that their mean is .5. However, I am unsure how to filter this remaining set.
I don't mind having to keep or get rid of a number in order to ensure the mean is .5. By that I mean the length of my sequence can be within $n \pm 1$ and I will be happy as long as the mean is one-half.
How should I go about this? Are there any other sequences/procedures that generate quasirandom numbers that are unbiased on the unit interval?

I figured it out by using the approach I described in the question, with help from this StackOverflow post. I also add or remove .5 from the sequence depending on the total number of elements requested and whether the sequence includes .5 (i.e. if the base is 2). For example, if base is 2 and I request an even number of elements, then .5 needs to be removed in order to ensure the mean is .5.
Here is an implementation in R. I use mnorm::halton to generate the Halton sequence to begin with. It doesn't work perfectly when $n = b^i$ for some integer $i$ but it works for all other $n$ (as far as I can tell).
haltonUnbiased <- function(n, base = 2L) {
  maxPower <- floor((log(n, base = base)) + 1)
  full <- halton(base^(maxPower) - 1, base)
  keep <- full[1:(base^(maxPower - 1) - 1)]
  cands <- full[(base^(maxPower - 1)):length(full)] 

  nLeft <- n - length(keep)
  if (nLeft %% 2 == 0) {
    step <- (length(cands) - 1) / (nLeft - 1)
    pick <- round(0:(nLeft - 1) * step) + 1
    return(c(keep, cands[order(cands) %in% pick]))
  } else {
    if (.5 %in% keep) {
      step <- (length(cands) - 1) / (nLeft)
      pick <- round(0:(nLeft) * step) + 1
      return(c(keep[keep != .5], cands[order(cands) %in% pick]))
    } else {
      step <- (length(cands) - 1) / (nLeft - 2)
      pick <- round(0:(nLeft - 2) * step) + 1
      return(c(keep, cands[order(cands) %in% pick], .5))
    }
  }
}

Due to the filtering at the end, the points are not as evenly/uniformly distributed as the unmodified Halton sequence, but it is still far better than runif.
I won't mark this as the accepted solution though as this seems a bit convoluted and I am wondering if there are any better solutions to the general question of "generate unbiased pseudorandom numbers."
